# How long does a 2 inch schedule 40 PVC pipe need to be to form a close connection between two DWV fittings?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

It seems like there should be a table somewhere, but I have not found an answer to this question. Obviously, I could do some trial and error, but I certainly don't want to end up gluing fittings to a length of pipe that ends up being too short to hold them together!

(Bonus points for a table or list of appropriate length for other pipe sizes!)

Comment: Cannot tell offhand, but all 2 inch diameter fittings will have the same insertion length.  Once one fitting's length is known, then double that will be the shortest you can cut to size.

Comment: One reason to why you do a dry run before gluing, and measure twice before cutting.

Comment: Dry-fit PVC/ABS does not fit up the same as when you actually assemble it with solvent cements - the hubs are *slightly tapered,* the primer and cement soften the pipe, so it **goes in further** when you actually assemble it than it does on a dry fit. So if you dry fit it "perfect" it will come up short on final assembly; unless you don't assemble it correctly, and then it may leak. Dry fitting is also a bit risky since the parts can jam rather hard on the taper.

Comment: Agreeing with @Ecnerwal here -- this is exactly why I am asking the question! In my (admittedly limited) experience dry fitting doesn't get you the answer unless you jamb the parts together so tightly you can't get them apart... and then you still don't know the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick ruler in socket. Multiply by 2 and add 1/8".

If paranoid, stick ruler in *both* sockets and add those, and add the 1/8" but generally they are the same. However, in looking for the desired "chart" I see that while 1-1/4" seems to be a common "insertion depth" for 2" PVC fittings, even for one manufacturer, some fittings are significantly different. The ruler is more dependable.

Comment: I guess this is how I am used to "solving" the problem. But you do face the problem that @Ecneral (oh, that's you!) pointed out in the comment above. I was hoping there was some "textbook" answer. I guess I am a little paranoid.

Comment: If in doubt, going a bit longer probably won't hurt anything. That's been my uneducated approach, try to avoid anything that critical.. PVC does flex a bit...

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal. I think you've convinced me that that's the best answer I am going to get!